# Can someone please explain this gas water heater thermostat marking

Tags: thermostat, water-heater

What I don't understand is the box with a slash through it located counter clockwise from the larger solid bar.

I'm sure it is less warm than the large box, but does it have a special meaning?

I don't get why they used a different marking for that specific one.

I did actually look for a manual online that might explain the settings, but I failed to find one that specifically mentioned this.

Make/model: white rodgers 37c73u-725

[image]

Comment: Have you consulted the Fine Manual? We cannot, since you have failed to provide such details as the make & model, and if it's explained anywhere, that would be where.

Comment: Perhaps it is the manufacturers recommended setting to avoid scalding.

Comment: https://climate.emerson.com/documents/37c73u-water-heater-thermostat-control-instructions-en-us-1569504.pdf

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but the problem is that it doesn't match the knob in the picture. Is it perhaps a replacement knob? In any case, my question would still remain the same :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, according to a manual I was able to finally find, the box with a slash through it indicates 120F (similar to the triangle commonly seen). Each marking above that represents a 10F increase in water temperature. I am going to guess that they wanted to indicate a scald free setting and a typical setting differently; my understanding is that 120F does not sanitize, but 130F will.

[image]